# How to replace closure variables with additional function call arguments to avoid constantly re-creating functions?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Given:

```
list = [ "one", "something", "other" ];
foo = function () {
    var str = "something", 
        bar = function (el, idx, array) {return el === str;};
    return list.some(bar);
}; 
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
   foo(); // true
}
```

bar is called by list.some() with three arguments.

If I want define bar outside of foo then I have to give it str in a closure like this:

```
list = [ "one", "something", "other" ];
bar = function (str) {
    return function baz(el, idx, array) {return el === str;};
}
foo = function () {
    var str = "something"; 
    return list.some(bar(str));
}; 
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
   foo(); // true
}
```

So with every call to bar, a function baz is created / defined within bar.  Can the closure and constant function re-creation be avoided by adding an extra
argument to the list.some() call of bar like this:

```
list = [ "one", "something", "other" ];
bar = function (el, idx, array, str) {return el === str;};
// Do something to bar's argument list so it's called with more than three arguments?
baz = function (str) {return bar(el, idx, array, str);}; // ????
foo = function () {
    var str = "something";
    return list.some(baz(str));
};
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
   foo(); // true
}
```

Updated: Note that foo can be called from within a loop as in the above examples. 
Can the recreation of all the functions be avoided such that each function is only created once?

I would like to pass bar four arguments (or any number of arguments after the first three, like this bar = function (el, idx, array, str, ...). The goal being to create any one function only once.  No outside libraries, please.

Comment: btw, the code does not work if the element is found at index zero.

Comment: I think this could be done with functional programming approaches such as currying and function composition. Let me do some tinkering and I will let you know what I find out.

Comment: Keep in mind that `bar` is only called once in your 2nd example. It's the function that it returns that gets called over and over. It's only being created one time.

Comment: @DonovanM Yes, it's the annonymous function within bar that gets recreated each time. I edited the post to call it "baz".  It's the recreation of baz I want to avoid.

Comment: @esnm Check out my solution using currying. I think it is what you're looking for

Comment: @esnm Sorry, just saw your reply. What I meant was that since `bar` only gets called once, `baz` is only created once. `list.some` is not calling `bar(str)` over and over (which means it's not creating `baz` over and over) - it's calling a single `baz` over and over. `bar(str)` is evaluated before `list.some` receives it. Put a `console.log` in `bar` before returning `baz` and you'll see that it's only called once.

Comment: @DonovanM Yes, in my example that is true.  However if foo is called within a loop, then bar is called for every loop occurrence, ergo bar would recreate baz each time. I will update the question to show this.

Comment: @esnm, could you tell, what exactly you see wrong with creation of new function? Is it performance that you are after or something else? Are you fighting need to re-compile some pieces of code into function? Are you trying to reduce garbage collection? What is your real goal?

Comment: @SergGr Many reasons.  Performance, lines of code within a function (cleaner code to not nest function creation, keeps the outer function smaller), reduced memory usage, avoid closure related problems.  Performance example: https://jsperf.com/closure-vs-name-function-in-a-loop/2

Comment: @esnm, where are `el, idx, array` getting populated from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can do this using a functional programming approach called [Currying](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry) ([Helpful article](https://jsleao.wordpress.com/2015/02/22/curry-and-compose-why-you-should-be-using-something-like-ramda-in-your-code/)). I think you could get technical and say that ramda is creating another function under the covers, which is true, however, it defines and returns the function 1 time, rather than for each iteration, which I believe is what you were aiming to accomplish.

The code would look like the following:

```js
var ramda = R; // alias ramda library from default R for clarity
list = [ "one", "something", "other" ];
var bar = ramda.curry(function (str, el, idx, array) {
    return el === str;
});
var foo = (function (array) {
    var str = "something", 
    // bar(str) creates a function one time that is passed to .some(),
    // rather than for each iteration
    foundIt = array.some(bar(str)); 
    return foundIt;
}(list));

console.log(foo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.23.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Keep in mind, the use of the ramda library specifically is not necessary, as you can implement currying yourself with vanilla JS, or with other common libraries (like lodash).

As per request - to curry a function yourself in JS, it would look like the following: ([Copied from this article](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2015/01/14/gettin-freaky-functional-wcurried-javascript/))

```
function curry(fx) {
  var arity = fx.length;

  return function f1() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    if (args.length >= arity) {
      return fx.apply(null, args);
    }
    else {
      return function f2() {
        var args2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        return f1.apply(null, args.concat(args2)); 
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: How to do this with vanilla JS?  Looking into how ramda does this, but would prefer to avoid outside libraries.  Also, creating another function is fine as long as it is only created one time and not with every call to another function.

Comment: @esnm Added the vanilla JS curry for ya =)

Comment: So this boils down to using f1.apply.  I can take f1 and f2 out of fx to avoid recreating those with every call.   I will try to do something with f1.apply() and see if that does it.

Comment: @esnm Not quite. Yes, f1.apply() is used, but not in the way you think it is. You should read up on the article I linked in my post (I had the wrong url in there, but I just fixed it), it will explain it pretty well. The idea is that it will return a new function until the original arguments length requirement has been satisfied. In the case here, it starts with a function of 4 parameters, we pass it 1, it returns a function now wanting 3 parameters, then `.some()` passes it the 3 and then it is satisfied, so it proceeds to running the function... if that makes sense lol

Comment: @esnm Here are some examples that may help make more sense: https://repl.it/Hvoa/0

Comment: Have not had time to fully figure this out yet, but I'm convinced enough to believe this is the right approach.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It could be:

```js
var list = [ "one", "something", "other" ];
var bar = function (el, idx, array) { return el === this.str; };
var foo = (function () {
    var str = "something"; 
    return list.some(bar.bind({str}));
}()); 
console.log(foo)
```

But I don't know if i have really understood you.

Comment: Works, but depends on "this".  Can an extra argument be added instead?

Comment: Explain why this works. Explain passing the `this` context. Why does it need to be an object? How else could it be used? Etc.

Comment: @esnm You can add as many properties to the object being passed into the `this` context as you'd like. `.bind({str: str, str2: str2 ... etc.})`

Comment: @mhodges.  True, but I would like to avoid "this" since I may want to use it another context.

Comment: @esnm Which is what I figured, and why I didn't post this solution 15 mins ago haha

Comment: `.bind` still creates a new function

Comment: @esnm I may not understand the real problem, it's the only approach i have figured out.

Answer (score 2):

Using Function.bind will work setting the context, this, to the string. However, function.bind still creates a new function. Really, no way to create a closure without a function. They are dependent on each other.

I think this is the cleanest approach:

```
list = [ "one", "something", "other" ];
bar = function indexAndStringMatch(key) {
    return function (el, idx, array) { return el === key && idx; };
}
foo = (function () {
    var str = "something", 
        foundIt = array.some(bar(str));
}());
```

Comment: Creates a function with every call. Would like to avoid that (and not use "this" for this purpose).

Comment: esnm, so does bind. I'm saying you can't avoid creating a function and using a closure. They are the same thing essentially.

Comment: Which leads to what I'm asking.  Can a closure be avoided and instead simply add the variable directly to the function calls?

Comment: I feel like I'm talking to a wall... NO No no, they are basically equal. Closure === Function. Game over man¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Same.  The point is to not use a closure (=== Function).  Instead pass the needed variable directly to the function.  So no closure wanted. ;-)

Comment: Take a look at the currying answer.  Looks promising, once I figure it out.